# Send email on signin event across all regions

Tags: amazon-web-services

we're setting up a new AWS organisation with multiple acocunts. As we want to implement best practices, our plan is to create a break glass IAM user. As this user is only meant for emergencies, we want to get notified by email, if there's a signin.

I got it working that we get a notification if it signins in the us-east-1 region. Afaik IAM is a global service, so it's residing there. When I log in with the user in us-east-1 a mail is send, so far so good. BUT if I login in another region, no email is send.
The notification is done via a Eventbridge rule and SNS. Of course I could deploy the same rules in every region, but this sounds not like a good solution for me.
So how do I achieve this the best way?

Comment: You can route events in other regions to a single region. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-cross-region.html